# Overriding italicized list counters in plain theoremstyles

Tags: formatting, theorems, enumerate

Using a list environment inside of any theorem defined with \theoremstyle{plain} results in italicized counters.  That is, the following example

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{theorem}
The following are not equivalent.
\begin{enumerate}
\item $n$ is an even integer.
\item $n$ is divisible by 4.
\item $n$ is 3 more than some positive odd integer.  
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

produces italicized counters (1), (2), and (3).  How can I override this action?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify the label format explicitly:

```
\begin{enumerate}[{\normalfont 1.}] % (or \upshape)
\item $n$ is an even integer.
\item $n$ is divisible by 4.
\item $n$ is 3 more than some positive odd integer.  
\end{enumerate}
```

Alternatively, if you're not wedded to using the `enumerate` package, and you'll be needing this a lot, you can use the `enumitem` package, and set the label once:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\setenumerate{label={\normalfont\arabic*.}} % or \upshape
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
The following are not equivalent.
\begin{enumerate}
\item $n$ is an even integer.
\item $n$ is divisible by 4.
\item $n$ is 3 more than some positive odd integer.  
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```